# What's going on with Burning Chariot having psychic weapons and abilities but not being a psyker?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Burning Chariot (10th edition Chaos Demons Index, Balance Dataslate January 2024) has both an *Eldritch Flames (Psychic)* ability and a *Fire of Tzeentch [PSYCHIC]* ranged weapon. According to the core rules, it could only use these if it's a Psyker. However, it's missing the Psyker keyword.

Core rules (pg 38):

> PSYCHIC WEAPONS AND ABILITIES
>
> Some weapons and abilities can only be used by PSYKERS. Such weapons
> and abilities are tagged with the word ‘Psychic’.

Does this mean that Burning Chariot can’t use its Eldritch Flames or Fire of Tzeentch? If so how are these meant to be used?

Comment: Not an answer, because guesswork: It's a mistake. The core rule doesn't really *do* anything, because Psychic exists as a tag for other abilities to defend against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Psychic weapons and abilities work fine on non-Psyker models

This rule was clarified in Rules Commentary, and now reads as follows (emphasis added):

> Weapons with [PSYCHIC] in their profile are known as Psychic weapons. Abilities tagged with the word 'Psychic' are known as Psychic abilities. Generally speaking, Psychic weapons and abilities are used by Psykers, but **the absence of the Psyker keyword does not prevent a model from using any Psychic weapons or abilities it has.**

Answer (score 2):

Possible Interpretations:

Intentional Exclusion: This might be an intentional omission by the designers, meaning the Burning Chariot cannot use these abilities despite their "Psychic" tag. This seems unlikely considering the chariot's lore and connection to Tzeentch.

Oversight/Errata: This could be an oversight or an error in the datasheet, requiring an official errata from Games Workshop clarifying the intended functionality.

Special Rule: There could be a specific rule for the Burning Chariot allowing it to use "Psychic" abilities despite not being a Psyker. This would be similar to some Daemon Princes who can use psychic powers without the keyword.

Current Status: Until an official clarification or errata emerges, there's no definitive answer.

Comment: Given that this has been unchanged through the dataslates since the release of 10th, there's _some_ evidence this is intentional. But... this is GW we're talking about.

Comment: Welcome to BCG Stack Exchange.  Have you got any evidence to suggest one particular reason in your list is correct, or even relevant? There is a reason each question can receive multiple answers, and each user can even give multiple answers. A scattershot approach makes it difficult to properly curate the post, particularly with voting for the correct and helpful aspects (against the incorrect and unhelpful).